# How do I fix deployment error "OSSL_WEBCRYPTO_OR_TEXT_ENCODING_NOT_INSTALLED is not defined" when using ZEIT Now, Next.js, and Gun.js?

Tags: next.js, gun, vercel

I've been unable to deploy a Next.js app via ZEIT Now due to a Gun.js reference error, `OSSL_WEBCRYPTO_OR_TEXT_ENCODING_NOT_INSTALLED is not defined`. There are no errors when running in development mode on my local machine.

Just prior to the error in the deployment logs is the message "node-webcrypto-ossl and text-encoding may not be included by default, please add it to your package.json!" Doing so did not fix the error, nor did adding `@trust/webcrypto` as per https://github.com/amark/gun#additional-cryptography-libraries (I'm using SEA for user authentication) (EDIT: removed `@trust/webcrypto` from dependencies).

Stack trace from Now deployment logs:

```
Compiled with warnings.
./node_modules/gun/gun.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
./node_modules/gun/sea.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
./node_modules/gun/gun.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
./node_modules/gun/sea.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
Hello wonderful person! :) Thanks for using GUN, feel free to ask for help on https://gitter.im/amark/gun and ask StackOverflow questions tagged with 'gun'!
node-webcrypto-ossl and text-encoding may not be included by default, please add it to your package.json!
> Build error occurred
ReferenceError: OSSL_WEBCRYPTO_OR_TEXT_ENCODING_NOT_INSTALLED is not defined
    at /tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:13474:7
    at /tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:13301:7
    at /tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:13478:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:14596:2)
    at Object.md/m (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:14597:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:23:31)
    at Object.1TCz (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:865:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:23:31)
    at Module.VVmT (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:11281:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:23:31)
    at /tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:91:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/173ebd33/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:94:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
npm
 ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm
 ERR! errno 1
npm
 ERR! maptivist@1.0.0 now-build: `next build`
npm ERR!
 Exit status 1
npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the maptivist@1.0.0 now-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

`package.json` dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "directory-named-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "gun": "^0.2019.726",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.2.1",
    "next": "^9.0.3",
    "next-offline": "^4.0.3",
    "node-webcrypto-ossl": "^1.0.48",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0"
  }
}
```

`node-webcrypto-ossl`-related stuff in `package-lock.json`:

```
...
"gun": {
  "version": "0.2019.726",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/gun/-/gun-0.2019.726.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-LVSxhGwaemZbrirSk6fp2KXORLUyjs6bnssjSjl/OhwbfLv7fvMhNfaOZuorzYsehxqMKJvxyNdFq/mZNXpjHQ==",
  "requires": {
    "emailjs": "^2.2.0",
    "node-webcrypto-ossl": "^1.0.47",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",  
    "ws": "~>7.1.0"
  }
},
...
"node-webcrypto-ossl": {
  "version": "1.0.48",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-webcrypto-ossl/-/node-webcrypto-ossl-1.0.48.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-MWUkQ/5wrs7lpAr+fhsLMfjdxKGd3dQFVqWbNMkyYyCMRW8E7ScailqtCZYDLTnJtU6B+91rXxCJNyZvbYaSOg==",
  "requires": {
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "nan": "^2.13.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "webcrypto-core": "^0.1.26"
  }
},
...
```

`node-webcrypto-ossl` is visible in `node_modules`.

Please help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Next.js (`"next": "9.0.4"`, `"next-offline": "4.0.5"`) fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

@randy-morantes your `package.json` looks correct.

Could you try to share:

- The stacktrace of the error.
- Your server code that calls gun that causes this problem.

Comment: Edited to include stack trace. Regarding your second request, I haven't written any server code as I'm trying to keep things as "serverless" as possible. If helpful, the app repository can be found at https://github.com/rmorantes/maptivist.

My apologies for the delay!

Answer (score 0):

I am an author of the peculiar\webcrypto and node-webcrypto-ossl packages. Based on the source of gun:

https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/e0d85f02b567a43d39cda0fe71522b84ff52a08b/sea/shim.js#L25

It looks like they have not switched to peculiar\webcrypto yet. Try adding `node-webcrypto-ossl` to your package.json.

Comment: I don't quite follow, `node-webcrypto-ossl` is already in my `package.json` (see first code block in OP).

Comment: Sorry, I saw the @trust/webcrypto package and didn't look further; I am surprised both are in there. They would in theory conflict with each other.node. Do you see node-webcrypto-ossl in the package dir?

Comment: No worries! The reference to `@trust/webcrypto` in the docs is now gone so I'm guessing they just hadn't been updated yet. I've uninstalled `@trust/webcrypto` and am still encountering the same deployment error. I see `node-webcrypto-ossl` in `package-lock.json` (added code block to OP) and in `node_modules`.

Comment: we only use @rmhrisk 's code now, it is great! @trust/webcrypto not needed. Maybe zeit is failing to build with node-gyp?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem last night and finally successfully fixed it using some monkey-patch and hack around. The trick is taking *gun* and *sea* out of the webpack and react environment, then access it using *window.gun*. Also, gun seems running faster when it is not in webpack.

This is how I did it in my Gatsbyjs project:

Read this doc: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

1. Copy ./cache/default-html.js to ./src/html.js
2. Now start gun and sea in the  of html.js. You can load external js file from github or jsdelivr here.
3. Then in your gatsby react components, just call window.gun and window.user and enjoy hacking:

   if (window) gun...
4. Now run *gatsby build* and you can see it is built without error.